# updating URLID under URL Maintenance in peoplesoft

Tags: peoplesoft

What is the result of updating the URLID in URL Maintenance ? will I be able to navigate to the updated link from the page where this URLID is used ?

Comment: Also, How to know whether the Push Button/Hyperlink properties indicate that the Hyperlink destination is a PeopleCode Command? Is it something related to external link static and dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the target URL, you should be able to do that. If you have more details, please update your question.